Proof of Azuma-Hoeffding inequality for Martingales in MAB
Suppose in an MAB problem, $X_t=\mu+\epsilon_t$ represents the reward values at each period (for a given arm). If $\mathcal{M}(t)$ shows the set of periods until $t$ where a specific arm has been implemented, We can estimate $\mu$ by $\hat{\mu}(t)=\frac{1}{|\mathcal{M}(t)|} S(t)$ where $S(t)= \sum_{s\in\mathcal{M}(t)} X(s)$. Based on some texts, it is possible to find confidence bound on $\sum_{s \in \mathcal{M}(t)} \left(X(t)-\mu\right)$ using Azuma-Hoeffding's inequality. However, I do not know how it is possible to extend the proof to the case where we want to have a confidence bound on $\hat{\mu}(t)-\mu$ because we are dividing $S(t)$ by the number of observations. Also, if we can find a confidence bound for the latter, it is possible to find it for $\hat{\mu}^{new} - \mu(t)=\frac{1}{|\mathcal{M}(t)|+\lambda} S(t)-\mu$ where $\lambda$ is regularization parameter because it is possible that until some specific period, the number of times that that arm has been implemented is 0.
In the original Azuma-hoeffding's inequality, the number of random variables is fixed. However, in MAB, the number of times that we pull an arm is also a random variable. Because of that, I am not sure how we can apply this inequality.
Thanks

For reader's reference, MAB = Multi-Armed Bandit.
